# Change fontSize of Item of Listpicker in window phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two ListPicker. I have bound lpkfamilymemberfrom database and lpkpaymentmode from array value.I want to two as FullScreen mode and in full screen I want item font size 40. In 
lpkfamilymemberfrom I achieve font size 40 as I have done following code.But I dont know how to achive this for lpkpaymentmode becoze it has not any datatemplate becoz I bound it using Array.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16 21 0 20">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="43" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

   <toolkit:ListPicker Background="White" FontSize="44" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"     x:Name="lpkpaymentmode"/>
  <toolkit:ListPicker ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" Background="White"  FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"       x:Name="lpkfamilymember"/>
```

And Binding Code:

```
 String[] Mode = { "Cash", "Credit Card", "Debit Card","Net Banking" };

        InitCustomPickerDialog();

        this.lpkpaymentmode.ItemsSource = Mode;

        this.lpkfamilymember.ItemsSource = GetfamilyList();

     public IList<FamilyVO> GetfamilyList()
    {
        // Fetching data from local database
        IList<FamilyVO> FamilyList = null;
        using (ExpenseDataContext Empdb = new ExpenseDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<FamilyVO> ExpQuery = from Exp in Empdb.Family select Exp;
            FamilyList = ExpQuery.ToList();

        }

        return FamilyList;
    }
```

I have tried many code to set item size of lpkpaymentmode to 40 in full mode but every time it show some fix size which did not change.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ItemTemplateForPayment">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="40" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then applying like this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" Background="White"  FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateForPayment}" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" x:Name="lpkpaymentmode"/>
```

Comment: This was not working as I bind listpicker with Array values. So Using ur code display none.